# ArchLinux - install latest JDK with pacman -S

Tags: java, linux, archlinux

hi im using the xTern ternmanal for some reason I cand do  `sudo apt-get`  only  `pacman -S`  works.. I want to install the latest JDK.

Also second Question if i can.. how do I find out my mouse driver type so i can install though terminal. My mouse works I just need to 2 finger scroll to work... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I just found the answer :

```
pacman -S jdk8-openjdk
```